# From where programmers of Linux open source drivers know how to 'talk' with e.g. AMD GPU?

Tags: gpu, drivers, osdev

Is there any documentations what commands/data can CPU send to GPU to perform operations? I mean operations similar to those in VGA standard. Have drivers programmers to do reverse engineering of MS drivers to know how to 'talk' with GPU?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any documentations what commands/data can CPU send to GPU to perform operations?

Yes, some video hardware manufacturers has made the specifications of their GPUs public. For example AMD and Intel did.

- For AMD: some hardware specifications can be found [here](https://www.x.org/docs/AMD/old/) and [here](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#documentation).
- For Intel: information can be found [here](https://www.x.org/docs/intel/).
- For 3Dfx: there is information for few model like *Voodoo2*, *Voodoo3* and *Voodoo Banshee* can be found [here](http://darwin-3dfx.sourceforge.net/).

> Have drivers programmers to do reverse engineering of MS drivers to know how to 'talk' with GPU?

Yes, the [nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)) is an example of that. It is an open source driver for *NVidia* video cards, created by reverse engineering the proprietary *NVidia* drivers for *Linux*. The [limadriver](https://limadriver.org/) is an open source driver for *ARM's Mali GPUs* and [freedreno](https://github.com/freedreno/freedreno/wiki) is the same for *Qualcomm's Adreno*.

### VESA

Many video cards provide the *Video Electronics Standards Association (VESA)* standard interface which exposes some basic functionalities as setting graphical modes and providing access to linear frame buffer. Each video hardware manufacturer provides their own implementation which is called *VESA Bios Extension (VBE)*. Following are resources for VESA programming:

- [Introduction to VESA programming](http://www.monstersoft.com/tutorial1/VESA_intro.html#2.1)
- [VESA 3.0 VBE specification](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/vbe3.pdf)
- [VESA tutorial @  OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Omarrx024/VESA_Tutorial)
- [VESA tutorial using Bochs Graphics Adapter (BGA) @ BrokenThorn](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevVid2.html)

Comment: Where can I find some VESA documentation?

Comment: I updated the answer to include VESA related resources.